# Exploration tutorial for gazebo/erratic or P3DX

Tags: navigation, exploration, erratic, erratic-gazebo, p3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anybody know of any tutorials (or have personal experience) for using the exploration stack with gazebo and the erratic model or with a P3DX like actual robot. My team is trying to map a very large area and manually mapping has become tedious.

All searches have come up with using stage or very little documentation.

We are running ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04/12.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55882/exploration-tutorial-for-gazebo/erratic-or-p3dx/) by [general975](https://answers.ros.org/users/4254/general975/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure about the exploration stack, but you could try out the [hector_exploration_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_exploration_planner) package that we use with great success for exploration while participating in the RoboCup Rescue Robot League. There currently isn't an example available interacting with the navigation stack, but implementing a node that calls the service provided by the [hector_exploration_node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_exploration_node) and feeds the provided goals to move_base should be straightforward.

Two examples of exploration in (gazebo) simulation:
[image: Maze]

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3